# How to read text file from external storage in android phone

Tags: android, usb-otg

I want to read a file from android application . This file is in external storage ( pendrive) connected to android tablet via OTG cable .

I have searched a lot on " how to do this " , but could not get any way . Can you please help me to do that ?

Comment: If you know the exact directory, why don't you just read it like you would in your code?

Comment: add permission to your manifest

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Which Permission will be Good For Connection USB Via OTG ? i have Tried External Storage Read and Write but i think its only for SD Card , Actually i want to Accesss Pendrive Via OTG and Move File from Sdcard to USB.

Answer (score -1):

Please Use Below code to read file from Ext Storage:-

```
String line, certstr = "";

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/mnt/sdcard/file.txt"));

        while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
        {               
            certstr += line;
        }                              
        reader.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found in /mnt/sdcard/", 2).show();
    e2.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} catch (IOException e2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e2.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The text file will be in pendrive . This pendrive will be connected to Tablet via otg cable . is the same code applicable for this scenario ?